# Fixing livekit frequent disconnection in Angular project

Tags: angular, livekit

am working on an event app that uses livekit for live event broadcasting.

I have implemented necessary events to get connected users media data. However, my app is not stable because users keeps getting disconnected unnecessarily even when internet connection is in good connection. I need to fix the frequent disconnection from livekit cloud service.

```
  this.room
  .on(RoomEvent.TrackSubscribed, this.handleTrackSubscribed.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.TrackUnsubscribed, this.handleTrackUnsubscribed.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.ActiveSpeakersChanged, this.handleActiveSpeakerChange.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.Disconnected, this.handleDisconnect.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.LocalTrackUnpublished, this.handleLocalTrackUnpublished.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.Connected, this.handleSuccessfulConnection)
  .on(RoomEvent.DataReceived, this.handleDataReceived.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.LocalTrackPublished, this.handleLocalTrackPublished.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.Reconnecting, this.handleReconnecting.bind(this))
  .on(RoomEvent.Reconnected, this.handleReconnected.bind(this));
```